# Copy rows of text preceding a table in word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working through Excel and Word using VBA. From Excel I have a macro to copy all the tables from a specific word file using a macro. It actually work perfectly. However, now I am trying to copy also let's say the 10 previous rows of text of the table because these rows can contain useful information about the content of the table.
I tried to find a method to get the position of my table or to copy text from a given position (row, column,...) but I found nothing.

My function to get all the tables from a word document is the following :

```
Private Function GetlisteTables(doc As Object) As Collection

    Dim tableau As Object
    Dim listeTableaux As New Collection

    For Each tableau In doc.Tables
        If tableau.Columns.Count > 4 Then

            On Error Resume Next
            listeTableaux.Add tableau
            
        End If
    Next tableau
    
    Set GetlisteTables = listeTableaux

End Function
```

I though I could use .Range on my table but this actually gives me the content of the table and I don't think it is useful in my case.
Is there any method that can help me to copy a specific part (especially right before a table) of text in a word document using VBA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Paragraph` object has a `Previous` method, which can return the previous unit as specified.

So the starting and end character positions of the previous paragraph to a table can be found using:

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Previous(Unit:=wdParagraph)
MsgBox .Start & ":" & .End
End With
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.previous

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I just want to notice that it is working for vba Word and not in Excel macro. I will probably do a two-part macro, one in Word using the `Paragraph` object as you mentionned to extract the text I am looking for and my main macro in Excel who will use what I obtained from Word.